# Гарантировать инлайнинг самовызывающейся лямблы

Tags: c++, lambda, inline

Представим, что в коде по какой-то причине есть такой фрагмент:

```
[&](auto x){
  someCode(goes(here));
}(abc());
```

или даже

```
int val = [&](auto x){
  int y = someCode(goes(here));
  return f() ? g(y) : y;
}(abc());
```

Можно ли быть уверенным, что компилятор заинлайнит такие фрагменты и сделает из них

```
{
  auto x = abc();
  someCode(goes(here));
}
```

```
int val;
{
  auto x = abc();
  int y = someCode(goes(here));
  val = f() ? g(y) : y;
}
```

Что если заменить `auto x` на `auto &&x`?

Если в этом быть уверенным нельзя, то как сделать, чтобы лямбда или гарантированно заинлайнилась, или код не скомпилировался вообще?

Кстати, у второго фрагмента есть интересный момент - если там будет какой-то сложный тип, то так просто он на объявление и присваивание не делится, но я почти уверен, что компилятор может и такое нахимичить.

Comment: В вопросе об имплементации компилятора не мешало бы указать используемый компилятор :) Потому что для общего случая ответ Вы и сами знаете: нет, уверенным быть нельзя.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, а слово `inline` вообще с лямбдами совместимо? Вроде его там и писать некуда? И атрибуты - тоже? Компиляторы интересуют все)

Answer (score 4):

Нельзя быть уверенным. Инлайнить или нет не оговорено стандартом, а значит компилятор не обязан этого делать. Ключевое слово `inline` никак влияет на это.

Если заменить `auto` на `auto&&`, то теоретически с помощью универсальной ссылки компилятору легче понять, что происходит. Но опять таки никаких гарантий на инлайн нет.

Comment: А насчёт второй части вопроса?